# the opening volley of a war between - what deos that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://finance.yahoo.com/news/heres-know-todays-apparent-confrontation-191340560.html

> But whether that amounts to a full-scale battle — the **opening volley** of a war between the Russian and Ukrainian states and a serious escalation of the current fight between Kiev and Moscow-supported separatists in eastern Ukraine — isn't entirely clear at the moment.

How do you understand the phrase **the opening volley of a war** and specifically the meaning of **opening volley**?

Comment: [volley](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/volley) sense 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Opening volley" means the first shots fired, in this case between the Russian and Ukranian states. [The definition of volley](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/volley) is "A number of bullets, arrows, or other projectiles discharged at one time".

> After a volley of arrows came from the opposing side, the Romans were forced to retreat.
>
> The army shot a volley of bullets at the enemy base.

It is also a [military tactic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volley_fire_(infantry_tactic)) where a group of soldiers fire simultaneously upon a commander's orders.